# swift uipagecontrol possible to change position

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a pageviewcontroller embedded inside a container view.

Then I am adding a pagecontroller inside my appDelegate file:

```
var pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = true
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

The only problem now is that the pagecontrollers bottom "margin" is too big. Even if I set my titles top contraint to the containerview as 1, the gap is too big.

Is there a way to remove the bottom spacing of a pagecontroller dots or -
put the pagecontroller dots on top of/inside the pagecontrollerview itself so that it wont be placed under it ?

[image]